# I keep running into Unexpected token ILLEGAL on a ajax post method

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm stumped on why it comes up? Does the jquery interfere with the javascript in this instance or is it something else?

Forgive me if it's a simply answer I'm new to ajax!

This is my code, it's a simply registration form with a password match validator. It displays the error on the .open() of the request.

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css"/>
<title>Email Client - Register</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="container">
    <header>
        <h1>Email Client</h1>
            <a href="login.html">
            <div class="topButton">Log in</div>
            </a>
        <h3>New User Registration</h3>
    </header>
    <div id="body">
        <form name="register">
            User ID:<input type="text" name="personID"/><br/>
            First Name:<input type="text" name="personName"/><br/>
            Surname:<input type="text" name="personSurname"/><br/>
            Password:<input type="password" name="personpassword" id="pass1"/><br/>
            Re-enter password:<input type="password" name="checkPassword" id="pass2"/><br/>
            <div id="feedback"></div>
            <!--Inline validation of whether the passwords match-->
            <input type="submit" value="Register">
            <!--If "user ID exists" is retuned, make it an alert, e.g. alert("That user ID is taken, please try another.")-->
        </form>
    </div>

</div>
</body>
</html>

<script>
var xhr=null;
function checkUser(){
    if (window.ActiveXObject){
       xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    } 
    else if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
       xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
    }
    if (xhr!=null){  
         xhr.onreadystatechange=Response;
         xhr.open(“POST”,'RegisterNewUser.php',true);
         xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
             xhr.send("Name=personName&Surname=personSurname&userID=personID&passWD=personpassword");
     }

function Response(){
        if (xhr.readyState==4){
                if (xhr.status==200){
                    var response=xhr.responseText;
        if(response.equals('registered'))
            {
                document.getElementById('');
            }
        else
            {
                document.getElementById('');
            }                   
            } 
        }
    }  
} 
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#pass1, #pass2').on('keyup', function(){
        var pass1 = $('#pass1').val();
        var pass2 = $('#pass2').val();
            if (pass1 == pass2)
                {
                    $('#feedback').css('color', 'green');
                    $('#feedback').text('Password matches!');
                }
            else
                {
                    $('#feedback').css('color', 'red');
                    $('#feedback').text('Password does not match!');
                }

            });
        });
</script>
```

Comment: `“POST”`.  Get rid of those "smart quotes".

Comment: @RocketHazmat Or when it comes to any programming language, "bane of my existence quotes"...

Comment: Thank you! been trying to work it out for an hour!!

Answer (score 3):

You're using the wrong kind of quotes in a couple of places.

You can delimit JavaScript strings with `"` (U+0022 : QUOTATION MARK) or `'` (U+0027 : APOSTROPHE) and never with `“` (U+201C : LEFT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK) or `”` (U+201D : RIGHT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK)